# Visual C++ values differ while printing and debugging?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I am checking a piece of code. Everything is correct but concept I am not able to understand.

```
double a = 0.001;
double b = 0.001;
double c = a * b;

printf ("%lf", c);
```

While debugging in visual c++ when i am pointing mouse over c after 3rd line it is displaying 9.999999999999995e-007 but while printing it is showing correct result i.e. 0.000001. I want to know actually what value it displays in debug tooltip and how it represents and converts.

Comment: just to clarify  ... you get the wrong value of c after 3rd line has been run ??

Comment: No. Actually its a precised value it is displaying in scientific notation(9.999999999999995e-007) in debugging tooltip. After printing in printf it is correct i.e. 0.000001. I want to know how it is converting and reconverting.

Comment: Well, the value printed by `printf` is rounded to it's default precision unless otherwise specified. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf: `Precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear after the decimal point character. The default precision is 6.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of rounding performed by printf.

The printf format %lf rounds to a default precision. From the top of my head, I think the default is 6, that is why you get 0.000001.

The debugger shows the actual content of the double. Due to the nature of floating point arithmetic, the result of 0.001 * 0.001 is not actually 0.000001, but an approximation although with very small difference.

By using other formats, you can see the difference. E.g. try printf("%.15e", c);

Comment: Ya its in mantissa and exponent form. But if you will look scientific notation of 0.000001 it will be 1.0000000000000000e-006 so why it is converting into 9.999999999999995e-007. 0.001 * 0.001 both are completely definite and will exact and perfect result 0.000001 so why approximation needed. Its not like I am deviding 7 by 3.

Comment: @BharatSharma IEEE-754 `double` stores the mantissa in base 2, not base 10. Neither 0.001 nor 0.000001 can be represented exactly in base 2. See http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046048048049 and http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046048048048048048049

Comment: @gx Ok I agree then how it can reconvert in 0.000001 while printing. If it can reconvert here correctly then why its not correct in debugging. I already read it from http://www.cs.duke.edu/~raw/cps104/TWFNotes/floating.html thats why I want to know the concept.

Comment: @gx_ Ok I understand now. You can explain it as an answer that wil be better.

Answer (score 0):

There are different implementations for conversion from double/float to strings and base on that you will get different results. The mos accurate implementation i know is `std::sringstream` and i know that is different from `printf` at least on IOS devices.

The visual studio interface as far as i know is coded in C# so you might want to look into how C# converts doubles to strings to get the answer you are looking for.

Razvan.